# git submodule update fails with error on one machine but works on another machine

Tags: git, git-submodules

I created a git submodule and pushed it onto our main repository. This worked fine and I can see the submodule in the repository via a browser.

To test it I tried to get the source in a fresh build tree.
First I ran `git submodule init` and then `git submodule update <submodule-name>`.

The second command failed with error:

```
error: pathspec 'x/mypkg' did not match any file(s) known to git. Did you forget to 'git add'
```

I tried adding to `.gitmodules` the url to the submodule but with no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely because you or someone on your team has changes in your submodule that are unpublished (committed, but not pushed to the remote server). They then published the superproject with references to the git commit in the submodule which does not exist on the git server. So git is trying to pull down a specific submodule git commit ID that it can't find.

This would be the case if the changes are in a repository elsewhere on your machine or on another machine.

To resolve, go to that repository that references that commit and publish (push) the submodule changes to the server. Or change the submodule to point to a different commit ID.

Comment: I think I had a very similar case but not sure yet. I had a library that I added as a new submodule and another submodule uses this library. I first modified the library, committed it and pushed it and then modified and pushed the submodule that uses it. No one else is modifying these in my case. Strangely, I cannot update the submodule that uses the library too.

Comment: @GauravSinha In any case, if you're getting the error on `git submodule update`, it is because the git repo cannot locate the git commit ID that the submodule is pointing to. Because you're building a "fresh tree" as you put it, either the URL is wrong, or you didn't push the commit that the submodule is pointed to.

Comment: What I figured happened is that I did not push changes for one of the submodules and kept pushing for another. Now, finally when I comitted the superproject, I made another mistake of using git commit -a and not doing an explicit git add :(. So, I broke everything. But I know the problem now. Thanks

Answer (score 39):

I also received this error using TortoiseGit while trying to **update submodules that aren't in the index**.  That is, they exist in `.gitmodules` but have not been correctly added to the repository.

The solution is to manually re-add them using the paths specified in `.gitmodules`.  You can use the TortoiseGit UI or run this on the command line for each module...

```
git submodule add <url> <path>
```

[image: Re-adding a git submodule]

*(I realise this is probably not the solution for the original poster, but hopefully it helps others Googling this.)*

Answer (score 2):

In order to get new submodules into other repositories, I believe you need to run `git submodule init` once before starting to run `git submodule update`; this will register the new submodule from `.gitmodules` in `.git/config`.

Comment: I did run git submodule init before running the git submodule update command. It does not help unfortunately. Updated my question to avoid confusion.